# highcharts Scatter Chart not loading with LOTS of data

Tags: highcharts

So i'm building a scatter chart that display some points in a row, basically showing a gap in time someone screwed up. For some reason when i get ALOT of data points the graph just loads nothing and i'm not sure why. But if i reduce the points it will load.

I sadly cant past the code here, its to large. But i set up a simple page where you can see it

http://beta.sc2replaystats.com/highchart_test.php

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the turboThreshold property:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold

Comment: just set mine to 1000000, you would think the least they would do it do a console log saying, ohh by the way we disabled your application because you exceeded your data limit.